# Solr, managing entities

Tags: search, solr, lucene, search-engine

I have the following situation when using Solr. My document contains "entities" for example "peanut butter". I have a list of such entities. These are items that go together and are not to be treated as two individual words. During indexing, I want solr to realize this and treat "peanut butter" as an entity. For example if someone searches for

```
"peanut"
```

then documents that have the word peanut should rank higher than documents that have the word "peanut butter". However if someone searches for

```
"peanut butter"
```

then the document that has peanut butter should show up higher than ones that have just peanut. Is there a config setting somewhere which can be modified such that the entity list can be specified in a file and Solr would do the needful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure that field to use a [`StrField`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/StrField.html) type, instead of a [TextField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TextField.html).  `TextField` is designed to handle tokenization and full-text search on textual content.  `StrField` treats it's contents as a keyword, and so does not tokenize.